# Let php PDO work with newest version of PostgreSQL (Debian/Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, postgresql, pdo

I installed PostgreSQL and the php PDO driver on my 14.04 Ubuntu like this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Which installed PostgreSQL 9.3 and worked fine, but now I want to run 9.5.
So I updated the postgresql packages by adding the PostgreSQL repo following  [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-postgresql-95-on-ubuntu-12_04-15_10/) and updating the packages.

However phpinfo still reports 9.3 after restarting apache:

> PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 9.3.10

I can imagine that I somehow also have to update the php5-pgsql package? But then how? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolved this issue but was struggling for some time, so I don't know exactly what the easiest method is to do. But I will describe a recipe which will probably work for others as well.

The first important note is:
I think I resolved the issue since I can use the new upsert feature introduced in 9.5 (INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ..). However my phpinfo() still reports version 9.3.

One more word about the problem situation: After adding the PostgreSQL repo and doing `apt-get upgrade` I had two version of PostgreSQL apparently.

```
ls /usr/share/postgresql
9.3  9.5
```

**So to fix I did:**

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postgresql
```

You will get a list of all the related packages installed. I deinstalled them all with --purge (this will probably remove all your databases as well, no problem in my case since they were empty).

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql postgresql-9.5 postgresql-contrib etc.
```

It gave me errors on some packages but when I repeated it, in the end all packages were gone. 
Also do this for the php pdo driver:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-pgsql
```

Now install postgresql again, only 9.5 will be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib php5-pgsql
```